# How to filter certain database with grep

Tags: mysql, grep

I wish to have the names of all the database names of the mysql server except for database names containing the word _backup.

So far, doing these will give me all the names of the database into a text file. 
This is to be executed in a centos OS enviroment.

```
 mysql -uroot -pxpwdx -e 'show databases' | tr -d "| " | grep -v Database | grep -v information_schema | grep -v performance_schema | grep -v mysql  > database.txt
```

How should I edit it such that it will not include those with "_backup" appearing ?

eg: say my mysql server contains 5 databases
a) db001
b) db001_backup20170602
c) db002
d) db003
e) db003_backup2017Aug

I only want (a), (c) and (d) listed in the database.txt file.

Thanks.

Comment: `grep -v _backup` ?

Comment: @salparadise - thank you for giving me an idea of what the statement I posted meant. I copied the code from elsewhere and it works but I didn't understand it - now I kind of understood that it mean database with names containing Database, information_schema, performance_schema and mysql will not get into the text file. So all I needed was an additional grep -v _backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution with Mysql statement,**

```
mysql -uroot -pxpwdx -sse "SELECT schema_name from information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT LIKE '%_backup%' or schema_name NOT LIKE '%schema%';"
```

**Bash Solution, with Show tables command,**

```
mysql -uroot -pxpwdx -sse "show databases;" | grep -Ev '_backup|schema|mysql'
```

***Notes,***

`-sse` option instead of `-e` will exclude headers, columns etc and will give only values to out.

`-Ev` option of `grep` will give provision to grep out multiple strings in a single statement

Comment: Thank you very much for (1) getting the principle of what I wanted and (2) for sharing how I can shorten the code using '_backup|schema|mysql' and (3) for guiding me to have a better understanding of what the code does.

Comment: Delighted to help you, (Y). . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query to get all databases without having "backup" in it,

```
mysql -uroot -pxpwdx -e "SELECT `schema_name` from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE `SCHEMA_NAME` NOT LIKE '%backup%';"
```

This will give you all databases without "backup" in it, you don't have to do grep.

Comment: your answer is literally all databases except backup. But not exactly what I had in mind (sorry the fault lies with my description - I have not specify exactly what I wanted and my description All Database and code "| grep -v Database | grep -v information_schema | grep -v performance_schema | grep -v mysql" doesn't seems to harmonise). Bec actually I didn't want those non-user created databases like mysql and schema databases.